# What does this text say in full?

Tags: cipher

Here is the ciphertext:

> Fhrmt z dvyhrgv gl wzgz-nrmv gvcg rh zyhlofgvob zyhfiw. Blf xlfow szev fhvw zmbgsrmt vohv, yfg blf qfhg SZW gl fhv gsv hkvxrurx dvyhrgv dslhv dvynzhgvi zoivzwb szgvh fh! Mld dv'iv zoo yzmmvw uiln zxxvhhrmt gsv kztv. Tllw tlrmt, blf ifrmvw rg uli fh zoo!

Your clue: With this cipher, "all" becomes "zoo".

Comment: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do

Comment: A piece of advice: Don't use really obvious codes. Just don't. You have to make it a lot more... interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an

> [Atbash cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atbash)

and it says

> Using a website to data-mine text is absolutely absurd. You could have used anything else, but you just HAD to use the specific website whose webmaster already hates us! Now we're all banned from accessing the page. Good going, you ruined it for us all!